# Half the widgets in Android Studio not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been learning Android development  and first noticed that the check boxes do not work, played around with it for a bit and noticed that half the widgets do not work. Even straying from the 'drag and drop' interface and simply writing the code doesn't work. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling and still get the same error:

> Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class android.widget.Checkbox

Details:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nCreateTreeFromCopy(JJ)J
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.nCreateTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.access$400(VectorDrawable.java:204)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createNativeTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java:837)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.<init>(VectorDrawable.java:812)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.mutate(VectorDrawable.java:268)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:817)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:329)
    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable$AnimatedStateListState.addStateSet(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:602)
    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.parseItem(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:525)
    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:453)
    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflate(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:385)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1224)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1197)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:315)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:681)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:89)
    at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:70)
    at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:66)
    at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:107)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:149)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:317)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Your errors are coming from the rendering work in the Android Studio drag-and-drop builder and/or UI previewer. Usually, I just don't use either of them, as they are unreliable, working instead solely with the layout XML. You could try toggling various settings in the toolbar above the drag-and-drop builder, particularly the API level drop-down (which probably is showing "24" on your machine).

Comment: Changing the API to 23 worked like a charm :D thank you so much!